# Normalizing features that represent the same thing

Tags: regression, logistic, normalization, optical-character-recognition

I'm working through the beginner exercise of classifying the MNIST dataset (recognizing hand written digits).
If I train with 80% of the dataset, then test the remaining 20% of the samples, I get ~90% accuracy.

Now, if I create a new sample by hand (using a 28x28 grid in a MS Paint-like application), the accuracy is much lower. Even if I try to trace out some of the basic shapes used in the training set, the results are spotty.

The input data for a given sample looks like this:

```
[
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
]
```

But instead of just having [0, 1], each value can range from 0-255 (representing the intensity of that pixel). I've noticed that most values are in the ranges [0, 80-120, 200-255].

The input data I create from my drawing application has values that range from 0-255 as well, but most values in the the ranges of [0, 200-255]. The drawing application creates a list with values only [0, 255], but then I apply a subtle gaussian blur to smooth out the image a bit.

## Question

Should I normalize the features before sending it through the classifier? If so, what is a good strategy for doing so?

## What a training example looks like

[image]

## What my hand-drawn example looks like

[image]